# How to Unit Test a Room Dao Query that Returns a PagingSource From Paging 3

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-flow, android-paging-3, android-unit-testing

My question is actually quite generic. I want to know how to unit test a **Room** **Dao** query that returns a **PagingSource** From **Paging 3**.

I have a **Room** **Dao** query:

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM database")
    fun getChocolateListData(): PagingSource<Int, Chocolate>
```

I'm wondering how this query can be unit tested.

What I've tried so far (using in-memory **Room** database for testing):

```
@FlowPreview
@Test
fun saveChocolateToDbSavesData() = runBlocking {
    val dao: Dao by inject()

    val chocolate = Chocolate(
        name = "Dove"
    )
    dao.saveChocolate(chocolate) 

    val pagingSourceFactory = { dao.getChocolateListData() }
    val pagingDataFlow: Flow<PagingData<Chocolate>> = Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = 50,
            maxSize = 200,
            enablePlaceholders = false
        ),
        pagingSourceFactory = pagingSourceFactory
    ).flow

    val chocolateListFlow = pagingDataFlow.testIn(coroutinesTestRule)
    Assert.assertEquals(PagingData.from(listOf(chocolate)), chocolateListFlow.emissions[0])
}
```

This doesn't pass, however:

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError:   Expected
> :androidx.paging.PagingData@7d6c23a1  Actual
> :androidx.paging.PagingData@321123d2

Not sure how to get it right. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PagingData` is wrapper around an internal event stream, you cannot compare it directly and the error you are getting is throwing referential inequality as expected.

Instead you should either query the `PagingSource` directly to compare the data in  `LoadResult.Page` or you'll need to hook it up to a presenter API such as `AsyncPagingDataDiffer` or `PagingDataAdapter` and use `.snapshot()`

```
val flow = Pager(..).flow
val adapter = MyPagingDataAdapter()
val job = launch {
    flow.collectLatest { adapter.submitData(it) }
}
// Do your asserts here
job.cancel()
```

if you need a test scope, I recommend `runBlockingTest` from the kotlinx.coroutines.test library

To query `PagingSource` directly, it has a single suspending `.load()` method, so you can simply wrap it in `runBlockingTest` and assert the result:

```
@Test
fun test() = runBlockingTest {
  val pagingSource = MyPagingSource()
  val actual = pagingSource.load(LoadParams.Refresh(...))
  assertEquals(actual as? LoadResult.Page)?.data, listOf(...))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As I'm only testing Dao queries, I don't want to deal with the UI. Can you tell me how to query the PagingSource directly?  Some sample code would help.

Comment: I added a small snippet, but essentially you can just called `.load()` directly. Depending on how `.load()` works, you may need to put some effort into setting which dispatchers the actual work is done on, so that you can take advantage of kotlinx.coroutines.test's pause dispatcher / delaycontroller.

Comment: Again, thanks for the reply. _actual.data_ cannot be resolved. What is the API used here? Do you have the link to the developer doc? I'm currently using _paging-alpha09_. Was it introduced in a later version?

Comment: LoadResult.Page is a subclass of LoadResult, so you'll need to check then cast using `as?` I'll update the code sample

Comment: Could you help me with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65810968/how-to-test-pagingdata-from-paging-3)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same code as you for testing but when I run the test several time it has different results on each run, one time successful one time fails. I have posted a question here too https://stackoverflow.com/q/67957325/2280316. would you please take look at it too. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer marked as correct I did my own, is not pretty but at least get the job done if any feedback I would be glad, thanks in advance.

```
fun <PaginationKey: Any, Model: Any>PagingSource<PaginationKey, Model>.getData(): List<Model> {
    val data = mutableListOf<Model>()
    val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
    val job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        val loadResult: PagingSource.LoadResult<PaginationKey, Model> = this@getData.load(
            PagingSource.LoadParams.Refresh(
                key = null, loadSize = Int.MAX_VALUE, placeholdersEnabled = false
            )
        )
        when (loadResult) {
            is PagingSource.LoadResult.Error -> throw loadResult.throwable
            is PagingSource.LoadResult.Page -> data.addAll(loadResult.data)
        }
        latch.countDown()
    }
    latch.await()
    job.cancel()
    return data
}
```

So in your testing, you can use it like this

```
val obtainedData = myDao.getSomePagingSource().getData()

assertEquals(expectedData, obtainedData)
```

WARNING: You are gonna see a rather extended log

```
WARNING: pageSize on the LegacyPagingSource is not set.
When using legacy DataSource / DataSourceFactory with Paging3, page size...
```

Comment: I fell on to the same problem, your solution worked really well.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you if need to mock PagingSource:

create helper class PagingSourceUtils.kt
Example :

```
class PagingSourceUtils<T : Any>(
    private val data: List<T>
) : PagingSource<Int, T>() {
    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, T>): Int? {
        return 0
    }

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, T> {
        return LoadResult.Page(
            data = data,
            prevKey = null,
            nextKey = null
        )
    }
}
```

YourTest.kt

```
@Test
    fun `should success get Chocolate `() {

         val chocolates = listOf(Chocolate(
             name = "Dove"
         )) 

        runBlocking {
            val tData = PagingSourceUtils(chocolates)
            `when`(dao.getChocolateListData()).thenReturn(tData)

            val data = ...

            val actual = ..

            assertEquals(actual, data)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct because you are mocking what you should be testing